# Why do async functions return promise of values not values directly?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I now understand that async functions return promises of values not values directly. But what I don't understand is what the point of doing that in the first place. As far as I understand, async functions are used to synchronize code inside them, now after we got the value from a promise using the await statement inside the async function, why should we return another promise? Why don't we just return the result directly or return void?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you can't know when the asynchronous call will be done. So it just returns a promise to let you make your rest logic with asynchronous call by making `then`-s chain.

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't calling the async function will stop all subsequent code in the caller function anyway?

Comment: At first glance true. but actually no. `async/await` just wraps your codes into promises under the hood and makes them as `then` functions chain. It is just a sugar in the language

Comment: Thanks, I am more confused now tbh, I will experiment with this to understand it more

Comment: I just don't understand what the point of the specifier "async" is now. If it's useless, why don't we just have the await statement directly? I thought the async specifier is used by the interpreter to stop all subsequent code in caller function

Comment: In the caller function if it is declared using async. But it will create for you again a promise with `then`. Your code will divided in some parts, and in one part, when you have used async/await, that part will be paused, not all. There will be not a single flow, but many. And in one flow that statement after the await will be paused.

Comment: I know this took so long and I apologize, I have a question: if we this `const mf = async (arg) => {
 await setTimeout(() => console.log(arg), 1000);
};

mf(1);
mf(2);
`
according your answer, we cannot guarantee 100% that `1` is always shown before `2`, right?

Comment: `await` statements accept promise-like objects as arguments, Since `setTimeout` doesn't return a promise, that is identical to if you just did `setTimeout(() => console.log(1, 1000)); setTimeout(() => console.log(2, 1000));`. `1` will always print before `2` because they were queued up in that order, but that is not in any way affected by the usage of `async`.

Answer (score 2):

> async functions are used to synchronize code inside them

They aren't. `async` functions provide syntactic sugar for promises, thus eliminating the need to use callbacks. `async` function acts exactly like regular function that returns a promise.

There's no way how the result can be returned synchronously from asynchronous function.

If the result should be returned from `async` function, it should be called and `await`ed inside another `async` function, and so on - possibly up to application entry point.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `async function` are used to sequentialise the code **inside** them. They do not - cannot - stop the code execution outside of them. As you probably remember, **blocking is bad**.  You cannot get the result from the future of course, but you don't want to stop the world just to wait for that function to finish either. And that's why when you call such a function, you get back a promise that you either `await`, or can schedule a callback on and do other things while it waits.